Как заменить в dataframe данные в столбце?
есть таблица dataframe:
      BSC Reg  BS_number
0  12  SA        135
1  12  SA        135
2  12  SA        135
3  39853  SA        620
4  39853  SA        620
5  39853  SA        620
6  39853  SA        621
7  39853  SA        621
8  39853  SA        621

и словарь:
{'89118': 'BR067', '28': 'IR028', '120': 'IK120', '39602': 'IK135', '40877': 'IR148', '40157': 'IR169', '40256': 'IK395', '41255': 'IR484', '39493': 'KM070', '91222': 'KH173', '39428': 'KH174', '38471': 'MG069', '34697': 'NS042', '18': 'IR138', '39853': 'SA068', '12': 'SH102'}

Как в python мне заменить данные в столбце BSC на значения из словаря? то есть получить таким образом таблицу:
      BSC Reg  BS_number
0  SA102  SA        135
1  SA102  SA        135
2  SA102  SA        135
3  SA068  SA        620
4  SA068  SA        620
5  SA068  SA        620
6  SA068  SA        621
7  SA068  SA        621
8  SA068  SA        621


А сами вы уже что пробовали, что не получается?

это очень простая задача. вы бы попытались сами ее решить.

Pandas.Series.map https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

@CrazyElf а то и replace, мало ли, словарь не полный.

в общем я решил путем создания новой тблицы из словаря. а там уже мержить две таблицы

Ну да, можно и так, конечно.
